# PreparedStatement is undefined error in jsp page

Tags: java, database, jsp, prepared-statement

I am new to jsp pages and trying to make a login page by checking username and password from the database. Here is the code:

```
protected void CheckUser(String username, String password)
{

    try {
        connect();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.PreparedStatement(
        "SELECT * Users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
preparedStatement.setString(1,username);
preparedStatement.setString(2,password);
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("cannot connect");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I get the following error for con.PreparedStatement

```
The method PreparedStatement(String) is undefined for the type Connection
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Edit: Here is my connection function:

```
 static String dbUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Bank";
  static String username="root";
  static String password="";

  static Connection con=null;

  public static void connect ()
  {
      try {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
       con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,username,password);
       System.out.println("Connected!");

      } 
      catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("not connected");

      }

  }
```

Comment: Can you show us the Connection object. Is it from the sql package? Where are you creating the Connection object?

Comment: @Junaid i edited the question, it connects and prints out connected succesfully

Comment: I create connection object in the servlet

Comment: Is the `CheckUser` and the `connect` method in the same jsp? And `static Connection con=null;`

Comment: yes they are all in the same servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about other stuff, but your query is wrong considering its not an typo, will throw `SQLException`.

It should be

```
   "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?"
             ^^^^ 
             ||||
             here
```

Comment: I did not understand, isnt this the same with my query?

Comment: @bigO Check the `^^^^` mark that section I have added. You forgot the `from` in your querie

Answer (score 4):

You spelled the method wrong [`Connection#prepareStatement(String sql) throws SQLException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29).

It should be `con.prepareStatement`, not `con.PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @BheshGurung Would you like to edit your answer and mention the `sql` querie problem. Then I will delete my answer as its not correct answer to asked question rather answer to upcoming Exception.

Comment: @Smit: Answer does not need to be right on the spot, but it must be something helpful. And your answer actually is helpful. +1.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to create a Prepared Statement by doing `PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("your Query");`
2. You need the `from` keyword in your Query.

Hence, your code should look like

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from Users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
```